# How to read mathematical formulas in English?

Tags: learning

I am trying to learn a coding language while learning the same I realized the codes are simple English sentence converted into complex codes using special character similar to that of short-hand.

For example
{names(M_dash)[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]]}

In the above example the function output is 10 column names with values in decreasing order.

My question is : Is there any handbook where I can get the English interpretation of mathematical functions and special characters.
for Example dx/dy in simple English is rate of change of x with respect to y

Please help.

Regards
Jitendra

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English but about translating expressions from some conventional notation or programming language into English. Such expressions vary from one 'language' to another, so the only authoritative reference is the documentation for the particular discipline or programming language in which you are working.

Comment: The answer is that you should consult an English-speaking mathematician. If you don't know any, you're not going to hear how specific formulations are pronounced. Further, the example posted here is a formatting expression, not a mathematical expression, and it's not intended to be pronounced, but to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker with a Masters degree in IT, I can confirm that such expressions are not spoken aloud, nor can they be. They are not mathematical, and the syntax differs between programming languages. All you need to do is understand the syntax for the particular language you are using and be able to employ it.